# Why trying to print the result of subtraction of two pointers throwing warning?

Tags: c, pointers, subtraction

I am trying to subtract 2 pointers such that they such give the number of elements.I could compile the program and run it .But after compilation it is throwing error as

> ```
> pointerarithmetic.c: In function ‘main’:
> pointerarithmetic.c:9:8: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
>  printf("%d",(q-p));
> ```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
    int a[5]={0,10,20,30,40};
    int *p,*q;
    p=&a[0];
    q=&a[2];
    printf("%d",*p);
    printf("%d",*q);
    printf("%d",(q-p));
    return 0;
    }
```

The expected output should be number of elements.

Comment: Hey, I reverted your edit, as it was bad formatting.

Comment: ok Sourav Ghosh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subtraction of pointers return a type `ptrdiff_t` (defined in `stddef.h`), not an int.

Use `%td` to print the result.